# MINIFS/MAXIFS formula breaks in LibreOffice Calc but works in Excel and Sheets?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to convert a bunch of spreadsheets from Excel to LibreOffice Calc and I have one formula that works perfectly in Excel and I even tried Google Sheets but it gives a #NAME? error only in LibreOffice Calc. I think it's something to do with the " " or maybe missing $ but I've tried a bunch of troubleshooting with no success. I'm new to Calc so maybe I'm missing a formatting rule...

The formula is supposed to create a min/max date range for an alphanumeric code that could be anywhere inside a cell in the range. It's used to show when an action started and when it stopped. It works perfectly in Excel and Google Sheets but not with Calc.

`=TEXT(MINIFS($master data.H:H,$master data.AE:AE,"*"&B3&"*"),"yyyy")&" - "&TEXT(MAXIFS($master data.H:H,$master data.AE:AE,"*"&B3&"*"),"yyyy")`

The formula should return something like 2003 - 2004 but instead it returns 1899 - 1899 for everything.

This version of the formula works perfect in Google Sheets:

`=TEXT(MINIFS('master data'!H:H,'master data'!AE:AE, "*"&B3&"*"),"yyyy")&" - "&TEXT(MAXIFS('master data'!H:H,'master data'!AE:AE, "*"&B3&"*"),"yyyy")`

Comment: While the functions like maxifs() , minifs(0 may exist in each application, did you check that the arguments are in the same places or order for each? If they are not and you did not edit as needed then that will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your sheet name is 'master data', which has a space in between. Different program quotes differently.

For Calc, you should use single quote after the $, like this:

```
$'master data'
```

So your formula should be something like this:

```
=TEXT(MINIFS($'master data'.H:H,$'master data'.AE:AE,"*"&B3&"*"),"yyyy")&" - "&TEXT(MAXIFS($'master data'.H:H,$'master data'.AE:AE,"*"&B3&"*"),"yyyy")
```

In the future, if you run into issues with formula, you should break down the long formula, and try to solve each issue as you encounter it. So for this case, I simply tried to see how Calc would reference another sheet by entering `=` then click on a cell (say A1) in "master data". The result was:

```
=$'master data'.A1
```